# Activiti Engine Process Definition Listeners

Tags: java, bpmn, activiti

I am building a solution on top of the Activiti Engine (5.9). I need to take some actions right after a new process definition (*.bpmn20.xml) has been deployed or undeployed.

I found a post in the Activiti Forums ([post here](http://forums.activiti.org/en/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=2316&p=18102)) with some pointers, like hooks for new a process XML definition being parsed or building some logic around the engine database tables. The post is almost a year old; I am hoping that the situation has changed since then.

So, my question is twofold:

To the people who might have had a similar requirement, how did you approach the problem and what were the pros and cons of your solution?

To the the Activiti project owners, is such a feature considered for the roadmap?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar problem were we needed to "hack" into the engine. We hoped Activiti will create a central bus or notifications but it seems it will take some time for what we understood. I have wrote a blog post [here](http://developer4life.blogspot.co.il/2012/02/extending-task-service-in-activiti.html), where you can see what we did. Hope it will help...

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer and share the link to your blog post. I will definitely take a look.